# Arduino: How to use PROGMEM to (readably) initialize a structure

Tags: arduino, progmem

I've got this:

```
typedef struct menu_item_def {
  byte x; byte y;        // Coordinates of the start for the line of test
  byte selected;         // set to 1 if the menu buttons have this option selected
  char *mtext;           // What to say, including sprintf placeholders:  eg: "STOP TIMER...% 4.2i MIN"
  byte mdatatype1;       // 0 means this is actual data to print.  1 means go call the supplied function to get the data when needed.
  void *mdata1;          // Where to get any data from for the menu (upto 2 different bits allowed per line)
} menu_item_type;
```

And then this:-

```
struct menu_item_def sub_menu_items[MAX_MENU_LINES] = {
  {1,2,0, "MOTOR RPM.....% 5.1i RPM"  ,0,(void *)8500,0,0},
  {1,2,1, "ALARM MAX....% 5.2f Lt/Hr" ,0,(void *)85,0,0},
  {1,2,0, "ALARM MIN.... %s"          ,2,(void *)"ON/OFF",0,0},
};
```

So I can later pass my menus to functions like this:

```
  Menu(sub_menu_items);
```

How do I move all that into FLASH ?

I've tried a pile of combinations of stuff, but nothing reduces the "Global variables use 688 bytes (33%)" message, except this messy kludge:

```
const char string_0[] PROGMEM = "STOP TIMER....% 5.1i MIN"; 
struct  menu_item_def main_menu_items[MAX_MENU_LINES] = {
    { 1,2,0, (char *)string_0  ,0, (void *)83,0,0 },
    { 1,2,1, "CHEM RATE...% 5.2i Lt/Hr" ,1, (void *)DemoData,0,0 },
    { 1,2,0, "CHEM PUMP....... %s"          ,2, (void *)"ON/OFF",0,0 },
};
```

which destroys my ability to code readable menus into my source, and triples all menu efforts along the way...

How can I somehow make this work, while keeping a "definition" of a line of my menu to be all-in-one-line inside my source code?

Comment: I am thinking this is not possible.

Comment: It looks like arduino (atmega) has not been designed so well, and requires some special kind of opcode to read flash instead of sram, which thus makes it impossible to use those 2 things interchangeably in any kind of general way?

Comment: Idea!  - Maybe I need to use Macros ?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do, assuming the strings are similar length, is to make the string a fixed-length array, eg.

```C++
typedef struct menu_item_def {
  byte x; byte y;        // Coordinates of the start for the line of test
  byte selected;         // set to 1 if the menu buttons have this option selected
  char mtext [30];       // What to say, including sprintf placeholders:  eg: "STOP TIMER...% 4.2i MIN"
  byte mdatatype1;       // 0 means this is actual data to print.  1 means go call the supplied function to get the data when needed.
  void *mdata1;          // Where to get any data from for the menu (upto 2 different bits allowed per line)
} menu_item_type;
```

Now the entire structure can be in PROGMEM, eg.

```C++
const struct menu_item_def sub_menu_items[MAX_MENU_LINES] PROGMEM = {
  {1,2,0, "MOTOR RPM.....% 5.1i RPM"  ,0,(void *)8500,0,0},
  {1,2,1, "ALARM MAX....% 5.2f Lt/Hr" ,0,(void *)85,0,0},
  {1,2,0, "ALARM MIN.... %s"          ,2,(void *)"ON/OFF",0,0},
};
```

To access the string data you need a suitable intermediate function, eg.

```C++
// Print a string from Program Memory directly to save RAM 
void printProgStr (const char * str)
{
  char c;
  if (!str) 
    return;
  while ((c = pgm_read_byte(str++)))
    Serial.print (c);
} // end of printProgStr
```

For the other values use `pgm_read_byte` or `pgm_read_word` as appropriate.

---

#### Reference

[Putting constant data into program memory (PROGMEM)](http://www.gammon.com.au/progmem)

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell - Macros must be used - it is impossible any other way owing to the architecture of the chip and the way PROGMEM works.

The following illustrates what I've implemented, and is more-or-less "the answer".

The end of this code is the "Readably init structure" part - the MAKE_MENU macro.

The start of the code is all support stuff to help the macro.

Be warned: there are all kinds of size and line-end limits and bugs in arduino: if you're using this, compile often and frequently - it's impossible to debug macro errors, so you must not allow mistakes to creep in.

For any of you scratching your head: PROGMEM lets you put some stuff in FLASH (which you've got lots of) instead of storing it in SRAM (which is severely limited).  When you run out of space using arduino variables, you need to do this stuff.

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>  // This lets us store static variables in FLASH instead of SRAM

#define MAX_MENU_WIDTH 64  // Max number of characters on a single menu line, PLUS 1
#define SERIAL_RATE 115200 // The BAUD rate of the serial port


// This is the definition of each line in a menu.  Each line uses 14 bytes of SRAM
typedef struct menu_item_def {
  byte x; byte y;        // Coordinates of the start for the line of test
  byte selected;         // set to 1 if the menu buttons have this option selected
  byte mdatatype1;       // This number explains how to use the following 2 mdata* as output when needed:
  char *mtext;           // What to say, including sprintf placeholders:  eg: "STOP TIMER...% 4.2i MIN"
  void *mdata1;          // Refer to the "int Menu()" function for details.
  void *mdata2;
  void *mdata3;
  void *mdata4;
} menu_item_type;


#define Pv(a,b) a ## _ ## b
#define Ev(a,b) Pv(a,b)
// The following macro makes menu definitions easy-to-type, and stores menu text in (unchangeable) FLASH and menu data in (precious but small) SRAM
// These numbers should range from 1 to MAX_MENU_LINES.  Best not to edit these, or add more than 12: they're already at the absolute max size that an arduino macro can be.

#define FLASH_PART(n, m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11) \
                     const char Ev(n,0)[] PROGMEM=m0; \
                     const char Ev(n,1)[] PROGMEM=m1; \
                     const char Ev(n,2)[] PROGMEM=m2; \
                     const char Ev(n,3)[] PROGMEM=m3; \
                     const char Ev(n,4)[] PROGMEM=m4; \
                     const char Ev(n,5)[] PROGMEM=m5; \
                     const char Ev(n,6)[] PROGMEM=m6; \
                     const char Ev(n,7)[] PROGMEM=m7; \
                     const char Ev(n,8)[] PROGMEM=m8; \
                     const char Ev(n,9)[] PROGMEM=m9; \
                     const char Ev(n,10)[] PROGMEM=m10; \
                     const char Ev(n,11)[] PROGMEM=m11; 


#define MAX_MENU_LINES 12   // How many lines are on each of your menu screens

#define MAKE_MENU(n, x0,y0,s0,m0,t0,f0,d0,z0,q0, x1,y1,s1,m1,t1,f1,d1,z1,q1, x2,y2,s2,m2,t2,f2,d2,z2,q2, x3,y3,s3,m3,t3,f3,d3,z3,q3, x4,y4,s4,m4,t4,f4,d4,z4,q4, x5,y5,s5,m5,t5,f5,d5,z5,q5, x6,y6,s6,m6,t6,f6,d6,z6,q6, x7,y7,s7,m7,t7,f7,d7,z7,q7, x8,y8,s8,m8,t8,f8,d8,z8,q8, x9,y9,s9,m9,t9,f9,d9,z9,q9, x10,y10,s10,m10,t10,f10,d10,z10,q10, x11,y11,s11,m11,t11,f11,d11,z11,q11) \
FLASH_PART(n, m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11) \
struct menu_item_def n[MAX_MENU_LINES] = { {x0,y0,s0,t0,(char *)Ev(n,0),f0,d0,z0,q0},{x1,y1,s1,t1,(char *)Ev(n,1),f1,d1,z1,q1},{x2,y2,s2,t2,(char *)Ev(n,2),f2,d2,z2,q2},{x3,y3,s3,t3,(char *)Ev(n,3),f3,d3,z3,q3},{x4,y4,s4,t4,(char *)Ev(n,4),f4,d4,z4,q4},{x5,y5,s5,t5,(char *)Ev(n,5),f5,d5,z5,q5},{x6,y6,s6,t6,(char *)Ev(n,6),f6,d6,z6,q6},{x7,y7,s7,t7,(char *)Ev(n,7),f7,d7,z7,q7},{x8,y8,s8,t8,(char *)Ev(n,8),f8,d8,z8,q8},{x9,y9,s9,t9,(char *)Ev(n,9),f9,d9,z9,q9},{x10,y10,s10,t10,(char *)Ev(n,10),f10,d10,z10,q10},{x11,y11,s11,t11,(char *)Ev(n,11),f11,d11,z11,q11}, };

//FINALLY - Here is the "readable" way to initialize the structures (all the 7,8,9 stuff are placeholders for future expansion):
MAKE_MENU (main_menu_items,
     1,1,1, "STOP TIMER.....% 5.1i MIN"     ,0, (void *)83,          (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,2,1,  "CHEM ON/OFF....%s"            ,2, (void *)"ON/OFF",    (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,3,0,  "MOTOR RPM......% s RPM"       ,1, (void *)ReadRPM,     (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,4,1,  "TOT CHEM RATE..% 5.2i L/Hr"   ,1, (void *)DemoData,    (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,5,0,  "TOT CHEM USED..% 5.2i L/Hr"   ,1, (void *)DemoData,    (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,6,1,  "CHEM 1 RATE....% 23.6i L/Hr"  ,0, (void *)83,          (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,7,1,  "CHEM 2 RATE....% 16.3i L/Hr"  ,0, (void *)84,          (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,8,1,  "CHEM 3 RATE....% 34.9i L/Hr"  ,0, (void *)85,          (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,9,0,  "PH READ........% s PH"        ,1, (void *)ReadpHVolts, (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,10,1, "PH: Min: %f Max: %f"          ,1, (void *)ReadpHMin,   (void *)7, (void *)ReadpHMax, (void *)9,
     1,11,0, "BATT VOLTS.....% s V"         ,1, (void *)ReadBatt,    (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9,
     1,12,0, "Msg:%s"                       ,1, (void *)DemoData,    (void *)7, (void *)8, (void *)9
  );
```